# Disk permission changed after open disk for write in Python

Tags: python, linux, apache

I'm facing into strange behavior. I'm writing to raw device (attached disk in Linux) in python using this code:

```
with open("/dev/xvdf", 'w') as disk:
    disk.write("aaa")
```

before I executed this code the disk privileges were:

```
brwxrwxrwx 1 root disk 202, 80 Apr 23 07:59 /dev/xvdf
```

After executing this code it changed to:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 80 Apr 23 07:59 /dev/xvdf
```

1. Why the file privileges changes after opening the file for writing?
2. Any solution for that? I need to file remain with the same full privileges.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why are you writing to the device? Can't you mount it first with Python? It's generally not recommended to operate on the device itself. Especially in such form (how do you even write to it? not even append? what result do you expect?)

Comment: I need to write data to specific offset in the disk. I want to be able to read the data after it  with a user that is not a root user

Comment: "to specific offset" - append? Write mode overwrites the file entirely when done on normal files. Also maybe binary mode? By default it's text mode.

Comment: But I'd suggest you find another way entirely - something that was designed to work with disks.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I confused append with "read and write" because they both keep already existing data. What I means is read+write mode, when you can use `seek` to get to the offset you want

Comment: problematic in my solution since the read is in other process. I want to know if it possible to open disk for write without privileges changes

Comment: What is root's umask?

Comment: root's umask - 022